# How to fetch redis data using id in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am trying to implement redis cache on a rails application. Till now I am able to cache the active record data using redis cache. I am able to fetch all the records at once using `get` method. But I am having difficult time figuring out how to fetch a single record using id since the the data produced by redis is in string data type.

Following is the data cached by redis:

```
"set" "bookstore:authors" "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Stephenie Meyer\",\"created_at\":\"2018-05-03T10:58:20.326Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-05-03T10:58:20.326Z\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"V.C. Andrews\",\"created_at\":\"2018-05-03T10:58:20.569Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-05-03T10:58:20.569Z\"}]
```

Now I am calling

```
authors = $redis.get('authors')
```

to display all the authors.

How can I fetch a single author using his id?

Helper method to fetch authors

```
def fetch_authors
    authors = $redis.get('authors')

    if authors.nil?
      authors = Author.all.to_json
      $redis.set("authors", authors).to_json
      $redis.expire("authors", 5.hour.to_i)
    end
    JSON.load authors
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, using a hash is probably better. You could use the following commands to achieve that:

```
HSET bookstore:authors 1 "<author json>"
HGET bookstore:authors 1 // Returns that author's json data
```

Or you can store each author on its own:

```
SET bookstore:authors:1 <author_json>
GET bookstore:authors:1 // Returns that author's json data
```